# kCGEventTapOptionDefault for CGEventTapCreate dose not work

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I pick up an old project of 2012 that modified mouse event in a mirrored window (horizontally flipped) to adjust mouse coordination using `CGEventTapCreate`. The project might work at that moment. But it does not work now. After several debug attempts, I found the 3rd parameter with `kCGEventTapOptionDefault` causes `CGEventTapCreate` to return `rull`. After changing it to `kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly` the function returns a valid `CFMachPortRef` like `<NSMachPort: 0x600003705380>` though I want an active filter event tap.
I tried to run my app under command line with root permission using sudo but didn't work.
I've set user permission on accessibility panel.
Here is the code:

```
  // Create event tap for mouse events
    CGEventMask mouseMask = ( CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDown)
                             |CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseUp)
                             |CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventRightMouseDown)
                             |CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventRightMouseUp)
                             |CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventMouseMoved)
                             |CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDragged)
                             |CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventRightMouseDragged));


    mouseTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, 
                            kCGHeadInsertEventTap,kCGEventTapOptionDefault,
                            mouseMask,(CGEventTapCallBack) eventTapFunction, (__bridge void *)self);
```

I compiled the app on macOS Catalina from a 2015 macbook pro.
Any thing I can do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by unclicking & reclicking the app in accessibility panel.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has been a bug in the System Preferences, Accessibility permissions since Mojave.